# How to extract certain field from JSON data

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm using mongodb change streams to watch over changes on collections and heres the JSON data it returns

```js
{ _id:
   { _data:
      '825E25A397000000022B022C0100296E5A10040BF97FA522F542A29973C2FD5990B85446645F696400645E243DF41D878D16693DA6710004' },
  operationType: 'update',
  clusterTime:
   Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1579525015 },
  ns: { db: 'test', coll: 'sourcecodemodules' },
  documentKey: { _id: 5e243df41d878d16693da671 },
  updateDescription:
   { updatedFields:
      { codeBody: '\n            \n\n        intmain\n          ' },
     removedFields: [] } }
```

Now I want codeBody field (inside updateDescription>updatedFields) as a string.
Please suggest me how to.

Comment: Which language and binding are you using to access the database?

Comment: server is on Node.js

Comment: Isn't it already a string? Can't you just retrieve it like `let codeString = obj.updateDescription.updatedFields.codeBody`?

Comment: tried that already, doesn't work. I guess it needs parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all you want to do is remove unnecessary end line & space characters from the codeBody, then you can do it like this

```
let str = db_obj.updateDescription.updatedFields.codeBody.replace(/\s+/g,'').trim();
```